# Tossing a coin with two random variables, conditional probability.

Tags: probability

I have a question regarding conditional probabilities.

Experiment: we toss a coin $10$ times. We count the amount of head and we toss that amount again. Let $X$ be the amount of heads in the first $10$ trials and $Y$ the total amount of heads.

Clearly, $X$~$bin(10, 1/2)$. I suppose $Y$~$bin(10+X, 1/2)$, but not sure about that though.

Question: what is $P[Y=5|X=7]$. But that seems pretty silly to me, because this basically says: 'What is the chance of having $5$ heads in total given that we have $7$ heads in the first $10$ trials'. Isn't that just $0$ since $Y \geq X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Clearly, $X\sim bin(10, 1/2)$. I suppose $Y\sim bin(10+X, 1/2)$, but not sure about that though.

Yes for the $X$, but the distribution of $Y$ cannot be binomial as the total number of trials is not a constant.  It is conditioned by $X$ as follows: $$Y\mid X \;\sim\;X + \mathcal{Bin}(X, 1/2)$$

> Question: what is $P[Y=5|X=7]$. But that seems pretty silly to me, because this basically says: 'What is the chance of having 5 heads in total given that we have 7 heads in the first 10 trials'. Isn't that just $0$ since $Y \geqslant X$?

Indeed, that is so. The joint support is: $0\leq X \leq 10, X\leq Y \leq 2X$

$$\mathsf P(Y=5\mid X=7)=0$$

---

Possibly they *may* have meant to ask for $\mathsf P(Y=7\mid X=5)$  Can you find this?

**Addition based on comments:**

> Thanks for the answer! If $Y\mid X\;\sim\; X+\mathcal{Bin}(X,1/2)$, then $P[Y=7\mid X=5]=({^{10}\mathrm C_5})\cdot(1/2)^{10}+({^7\mathrm C_2})\cdot(1/2)^7=0.4102$.

No.  You're given the condition that $X=5$ so you don't need to calculate its probability.

Perhaps it would be more clear to express the conditional distribution as: $(Y-X\mid X) \;\sim\; \mathcal{Bin}(X,1/2)$ , which means that: $$\mathsf P(Y-X=2\mid X=5) = {^5\mathrm C_2} / 2^5$$

*If* you wanted the the joint probability then you'd multiply (rather than add): $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y=7, X=5) & = \mathsf P(X=5)\cdot\mathsf P(Y-X=2\mid X=5) \\[1ex] & = {^{10}\mathrm C_5}{^{5}\mathrm C_2}/2^{15}\end{align}$$

---

> My teacher changed the question now, everything is kept the same but Y is the amount of heads in the second series of tosses. I suppose $Y\mid X\sim bin(X, 1/2)$, right?

Yes, and then in *this* scenario: $\mathsf P(Y=5\mid X=7) = {^7\mathrm C_5}/2^7$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If $Y∣X∼X+Bin(X,1/2)$, then $P[Y=7|X=5]=(10C5)*(1/2)^10+(7C2)*(1/2)^7=0.4102$. My teacher changed the question now, everything is kept the same but Y is the amount of heads in the second series of tosses. I suppose $Y|X$~bin(X, 1/2)$, right?

Comment: @Holograph, see above.

Comment: Thanks for the explenation! But how can I determine the distribution of $Y$? I have to show the dependence between $X=5, Y=5$, but that is hardly possible without the distrubition of $Y$. I tried a proof by contradiction, but that, of course, didn't work.